# How to debug the code passed to puppeteer's page.evaluate method in VSCode by setting breakpoints?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, puppeteer

For example, consider the snippet below.

```
const page = browser.newPage();
await page.goto(URL);
await page.evaluate(() => {
  // Some large code that sends web requests
});
```

Is it possible to debug the code passed to the `page.evaluate` method in Visual Studio Code by setting breakpoints? With default configuration, the breakpoints inside that region are not being hit. Is there something else I could do to debug this code from VSCode?

Answer (score -1):

just put `debugger;` inside:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  debugger;
});
```

from docs: https://pptr.dev/